# MFC EditControl onclick

Tags: visual-c++, mfc

I am wondering is there a way to handle mouse click operation on EditControl box? I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11565107/clicking-in-an-mfc-edit-box) when I was researching, but not able to understand completely, so is there a way to handle mouse click on EditControl, if so, how is that done?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to handle CEdit mouse click in parent form?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1506145/how-to-handle-cedit-mouse-click-in-parent-form)

Comment: check this answer, it explains how to use the class wizards if you are using visual studio http://stackoverflow.com/a/30096023/3906985

Comment: check also this page that explains the CEdit control https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f7yhsd2b.aspx